# Rails 4 subdomain routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I have the following in my routes.rb file

```
namespace :client, path: '/' do
    get  '/' => 'default#index', as: :default_index
end 

namespace :api, path: '/', constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }  do
    get '/' => 'default#index', as: :default_index
end
```

I have mounted a subdomain call "test.dev", and I can access "test.dev" without problems. However, if I try to get "api.test.dev" I get the same page as in "test.dev", **unless I change the path for the namespace with the subdomain constraint**.

Can't I have the same path for both even though one is on a subdomain and the other one isn't?

Answer (score 0):

@Rodrigo, I've just faced the same problem, and I figure out the solution \o/.

The problem is in your "api.test.dev". I'm not dive into the details of why's, but it should be "api.test-dev.com", so append ".com" to your etc/hosts and change it to be like that:

```
api.test.dev
```

**to**

```
api.test-dev.com
```